# Laravel 5.3 - No break between lines in mail notification?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I send an email out via the `toMail` channel, which is saved from a text area where I hit enter twice for new line, so it looks like this in the input:

```
Line 1

Line 2 with space above and below

Line 3
```

When I use that text in the mail like this:

```
return (new MailMessage)->subject('test spacing')
                        ->line($this->text);
```

It looks like this in the email:

```
Line 1 Line 2 with space above and below Line 3
```

I changed the relevant section in `email.blade.php` from:

```
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
  {{ $line }}
@endforeach
```

To:

```
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
  {!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line)) !!}
@endforeach
```

But that still didn't work. In the `notifications` table in the db, it is saved as:

```
Line 1\n\nLine 2 with space above and below\n\nLine 3
```

Any idea how to get the sent email to show the spacing so it's not just one big blob?

**UPDATE:**

So `laravel` inserts the notification with `\n\n` in the `notifications` table, but it is actually saved in the `model` table like this:

[image]

Which is what is passed to the `email`, but still not sure how to get those spaces in the `email`.

Comment: Perhaps the mail is being sent as html? if so try adding `<br>` where you would want your spaces?

Comment: Yup it's sending as html as expected. That's why I tried both `{!! nl2br($line)) !!}` and `{!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line)) !!}` but still don't get the space...

Comment: nl2br inserts linebreak characters only. HTML does not interpret line breaks. I think the best way would be to have a `<br>` tag before and/or after.

Comment: Added an update.

Answer (score 5):

Your input text contains line breaks which Laravel will strip out automatically (see the `formatLine()` method of the `Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SimpleMessage` class, which `MailMessage` is based on). You could either subclass MailMessage and override the formatting:

```
class CustomMailMessage extends MailMessage {

    protected function formatLine($line) {
        if (is_array($line)) {
            return implode(' ', array_map('trim', $line));
        }
        // Just return without removing new lines.
        return trim($line);
    }

}
```

or you could split your text before sending it to MailMessage. Since the "line" methods accept strings or arrays you can split the lines and pass them all in at once:

```
return (new MailMessage)->subject('test spacing')
    ->line(array_map('trim', preg_split('/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/', $this->text)));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it explains not just that you can use a MailMessage subclass, but also that you can simply pass an array of strings to the 'line' method. This was the easiest approach for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extends MailMessage

like

```
class MyClassMailMessage extends MailMessage {

    public function splitInLines($steps){
        $arrSteps = explode("\n", $steps);
        if(!empty($arrSteps)){
            foreach ($arrSteps as $line) {
               $this->with($line);
            }
          }
         return $this; 
    }
}
```

then in your Notification do this

```
return (new MyClassMailMessage)
    ->splitInLines($this->text);
```

Answer (score 0):

specify your email type as `text/html`. I think laravel does automatically but better to use views I think. The following is working for me.
Another easy way is create view for your mail text and use that like
Create Mailable as follows using view.

```
class CompanyCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $company;

    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("Alert: New Company added")
                ->from("fax@netinkvoice.com", "From1 Name123")
                ->view('super_admin.company-mail')->with(['data' => $this->company]);
    }
}
```

I have created this mailable and working fine, data shows in tabular format. I and its laravel 5.3.

Comment: It does send as `text/html` I think since it shows the laravel `button/css` and other email styles/colors header/footer/etc...

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep it consistent with the other email notifications in the `toMail` delivery channel file.

Comment: would you please post how you create $text and use as $this->text.

Comment: do you use notifiable at all? That's how I have mine setup, in the controller, I save the record to db and fire an event with the record data. The notification listener on the event gets passed the data to the constructor, and that is how I access the $text, which works, but again issue with spacing.

Comment: put <br> tag for each line in your message

Comment: how can I do that to try it out?

Comment: for each like `foreach($introLines as $line){ echo $line."<br>";}` something like this

Comment: yeah, I think that is what @hassan is saying too, but it is the `$line` itself that has the breaks, within that variable. I have to keep the question open longer, maybe someone encountered the same issue with the notification mail channel..

Answer (score -1):

simply add some html tags to make a wrap to new line

```
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
  <p>{{ $line }}</p>
  // or use <br />
@endforeach
```

---

however to add new line breaks to in markdown you may do :
1 -

> To have a line break without a paragraph, you will need to use two
>   trailing spaces with one `enter`.

[source](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lists)

2 -
use ordinary `<br />`

source : [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-markdown-messages)

Comment: That won't work for 2 reasons. `Laravel` now uses markdown for the email template, but more importantly, there may be many different `$line` used when composing the email template (standard laravel), so i wouldn't want that hard coded formatting to be applied to other lines, just this one `$line` that has spacing in the `$text` variable it is using.

Comment: laravel had added markdown , but you can still use html to template your emails .

Comment: You mean add `<br />` to `$text`> I wish I know how to convert it so it saves in the db as is, but on sending to email as `$line` it adds the breaks..

Comment: no, add `<br />` inside your email.blade.php , as laravel mentioned in the doc , you can use `<br />` in your markdown template `{{ $line }} <br />`

Comment: So i did that, in the markdown template but no change. The important thing to realize is that the {{ $line }} has to have the formatting/correct way to display in it, nothing after it can change what is in it, like the `<br />` after it, since it is within the variable where the spacing is.

Comment: then try to use html tags as i mentioned in my answer, i'm using html tags and works fine with me