# How to Print New Line in a foreach() content in Laravel-10 toMail() function

Tags: php, email, newline, laravel-10

I am trying to print each content of the foreach() array on a new line. I have used PHP_EOL as well as "\n". None of them works.
Here is my code below:

```
   public function toMail(object $notifiable): MailMessage
    {  //$user = Auth::user();
        //dd($user); // Check if $user is null or contains a user object
        $upcomingBirthdays = $this->upcomingBirthdays;
        $upcomingWeddings = $this->upcomingWeddings;
    
        $birthdayLines = '';
        foreach ($this->upcomingBirthdays as $birthday) {
            $birthdayLines .=$birthday->name .$birthday->birthday. "\n" ;
        }
    
        $weddingLines = '';
        foreach ($this->upcomingWeddings as $wedding) {
            $weddingLines .= $wedding->name.$wedding->wedding. "\n";
        }
    
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Upcoming Celebrants')
            ->line('Here are the upcoming celebrants for the week:')
            ->line('Birthdays:')
            ->line($birthdayLines)
            ->line('Wedding Anniversaries:')
            ->line($weddingLines)
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Thank you for using MyAnniversary!');
    }
```

I have concatenated "\n" to the end of each string. I have also tried using PHP_EOL character. None of them worked.

And here is a sample output of the code above:

```
Here are the upcoming celebrants for the week:

Birthdays:

Mrs. Jazlyn Lakin II - 2023-07-01 Mrs. Fiona Collier IV - 1958-07-03 Juliana Stamm - 1990-07-12 Guiseppe Kris III - 1993-07-13 Jewell Lang - 2003-07-23 Terrance Huels - 1975-07-26

Wedding Anniversaries:

Prof. Sherman Rath - 2014-07-06 Hettie Luettgen MD - 2001-07-06 Cyrus Gleason Jr. - 1998-07-10 Mrs. Jazlyn Lakin II - 2023-07-17
```

How do I make each **Name and date** appear on a new line in the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.3 - No break between lines in mail notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148100/laravel-5-3-no-break-between-lines-in-mail-notification)